# How to remove or reset USB drivers

Tags: usb, bluetooth, driver

This is a bit of a strange one. I've been using a Dualshock (DS4), aka a PlayStation 4 controller on my Mac pretty successfully for the passed couple of weeks.

Later I had plugged in my gaming mouse (Logitech g700s) and it automatically installed some basic drivers. Problem is, this completely broke the ability to use a DS4 controller. Unplugging, or restarting has no effect. The DS4 is will not pair via bluetooth and no longer works with just the cord.

So what I'm trying to figure out, is how I can maybe reset or remove those default drivers that got installed when I plugged in my gaming mouse.

I know this sounds weird, but I was able to reproduce the problem on a different Mac running the same version as mine.

Any help, or just advice on where I can look next would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: the objective here is to remove Logitech drivers ?

Comment: Did you install the Logitech gaming app ? or did you look for it in Terminal using "mdfind -name Logitech"

Comment: @Buscar웃 the objective here is to remove whatever initial setup runs when you plug in a new peripheral. Also for some reason when I plugged this mouse in, it brought up the "Identify this keyboard" prompt.

Comment: @Buscar웃 also I had installed and and uninstalled the official support for the mouse but that didn't work.

Comment: try using terminal "mdfind logitech" and delete all you can find

Comment: @Buscar웃 I removed some relevant files but no luck.

Comment: sorry, I should have said to use the AppCleaner.app to do that, since it will find all associated files and drivers to remove.

Comment: @Buscar웃 OK I'll try that too, but I'm not sure if this will help. When I had originally plugged in the mouse, I hadn't installed the official support. I think something quite low-level is happening here where a like shared bluetooth config file was edited when I plugged the dongle in.